# KeyError: 'col name'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to make an operation for each row and put it in a new column

I have col "likes" and col "dislikes", so I want to create the "ratio" col(new)
I take this from StackOverflow but it doesn't work

```
for index, row in data.iterrows(): 
    if row['dislikes'] > 0:
        data["ratio"][index] =  data.likes[index]/data.dislikes[index]
```

I want to avoid divide on zero, so if "dislike" greater than zero, execute  like/dislike formula

Comment: Add what you want your code to achieve and how it went wrong.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @HusseinSaad - If rows not matched condition `['dislikes'] > 0` need `0` in output? Check last edit of my answer if this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in pandas is best avoid loops, because slow if exist vectorized solution:

```
mask = data['dislikes'] > 0
data.loc[mask, 'ratio']  =  data.loc[mask, 'likes'] / data.loc[mask, 'dislikes']
```

Or:

```
data["ratio"] = np.where(mask, data['likes'] / data['dislikes'], np.nan)
```

EDIT:

In my opinion `NaN` should be changed to `0`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'likes':[10,20,0,0], 'dislikes':[5,0,10,0]})

mask = data['dislikes'] > 0
data["ratio"] = np.where(mask, data['likes'] / data['dislikes'], 0)
print (data)
   likes  dislikes  ratio
0     10         5    2.0
1     20         0    0.0
2      0        10    0.0
3      0         0    0.0
```

EDIT:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'likes':[10,20,0,0], 'dislikes':[5,0,10,0]})
```

Filter DataFrames by 2 different columns:

```
a = data.loc[data.likes > 0, 'likes']
b = data.loc[data.dislikes > 0, 'dislikes']
print (a)
0    10
1    20 <-different index 1
Name: likes, dtype: int64

print (b)
0     5
2    10 <-different index 2
Name: dislikes, dtype: int64
```

If want divide by different indices get `NaN`s because pandas try align data:

```
c = a/b
print (c)
0    2.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Also data are align if create new column - for index `3` which not exist in `c` is added NaN:

```
data['ratio'] = c
print (data)
   likes  dislikes  ratio
0     10         5    2.0
1     20         0    NaN
2      0        10    NaN
3      0         0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! that helps me

Comment: I try to run this code 
`data["ratio"] = data[data.likes > 0]['likes']/data[data.dislikes > 0]['dislikes']`
but it also return NaN value, Why?

Comment: @HusseinSaad - I try explain a  bit in edited answer. What is expected output of sample data `data = pd.DataFrame({'likes':[10,20,0,0], 'dislikes':[5,0,10,0]})` ?